# why is center of the circles still transparent in Canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm reading about Canvas element from MDN and came across an example for setting Transparency through globalAlpha attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
    
    canvas{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='tutorial' width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    </body>
    <script>
        let canvas=document.getElementById("tutorial");
        let ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle="#F00";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,75,75);
        ctx.fillStyle="#0F0"
        ctx.fillRect(75,0,75,75)
        ctx.fillStyle="#00F";
        ctx.fillRect(0,75,75,75);
        ctx.fillStyle="#0FF"
        ctx.fillRect(75,75,75,75)
        ctx.fillStyle='#FFF';
        ctx.globalAlpha=0.2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for(let i=1;i<8;i++){
            ctx.arc(75, 75, 10*i, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true)
            ctx.fill();
        }
        ctx.fill();
    </script>
</html>
```

In the above example, I'm creating 8 concentric circles each with transparency 0.2 . but I can still see the center of the canvas element.

Shouldn't the canvas center be hidden /opaque by 5 circles?

If I change the globalAlpha value to 0.4 or 0.5 I can no longer see the center of the Canvas element

Here is the example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
    
    canvas{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='tutorial' width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    </body>
    <script>
        let canvas=document.getElementById("tutorial");
        let ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle="#F00";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,75,75);
        ctx.fillStyle="#0F0"
        ctx.fillRect(75,0,75,75)
        ctx.fillStyle="#00F";
        ctx.fillRect(0,75,75,75);
        ctx.fillStyle="#0FF"
        ctx.fillRect(75,75,75,75)
        ctx.fillStyle='#FFF';
        ctx.globalAlpha=0.5;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for(let i=1;i<8;i++){
            ctx.arc(75, 75, 10*i, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true)
            ctx.fill();
        }
      
    </script>
</html>
```

Can Someone please explain ,

1. why I can still see the center when globalAlpha value is 0.2 and not it is 0.5?
2. Why stacking 2 circles with 0.5 opacity or 5 circles with 0.2 opacity does not make it complete opaque?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. If you put a glass plate on a surface, you can see the surface through it.

Comment: @Hiro Yeah, I understand that, But shouldn't we be unable to see the surface if we stack ,certain number of plates each with certain opacity?

Comment: I can't understand why stacking 2 circles 0.5 opacity or 5 circles with 0.2 opacity make it completely opaque?

Comment: Unrelated but you should really put your beginPath() **inside** the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition of opacity/transparency is wrong. In informal terms: When you draw a circle with 50% opacity, that means that the pixel values consist of 50% the circle and 50% of what was there before. When you draw a second 50% opaque circle, the pixel value consists of 50% the second circle and 50% of what was there before, that is 50% the first circle and 50% of what was there before the circles. Thus after the two circles, the pixel values are 50% from the second circle, 25% from the first circle, and 25% of what was there before.

In other words, it's actually multiplicative, not additive. Placing two 50% transparent things on top of each other makes the whole (0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25) transparent, i.e. 75% opaque.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm creating 8 concentric circles each with transparency 0.2

Actually that 0.2 is not the transparency, but opacity (the inverse). So 0.2 means 80% transparency.
Secondly, you are drawing 7 circles, not 8. Check your loop condition:

```
for(let i=1;i<8;i++){
```

> Shouldn't the canvas center be hidden /opaque by 5 circles?

Not necessarily. 0.8 transparency (0.2 opacity) is still a lot. Each circle leaves 80% transparency compared to the previous one. The second leaves 0.8 transparency of the first's 0.8, i.e. 0.8 * 0.8 = 0.64, and so on:

| circle | combined transparency | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.8 | 0.8 |
| 2 | 0.8<sup>2</sup> | 0.64 |
| 3 | 0.8<sup>3</sup> | 0.512 |
| 4 | 0.8<sup>4</sup> | 0.4096 |
| 5 | 0.8<sup>5</sup> | 0.32768 |
| 6 | 0.8<sup>6</sup> | 0.262144 |
| 7 | 0.8<sup>7</sup> | 0.2097152 |

So you see that after the 7<sup>th</sup> circle has been drawn there is still some 21% transparency.

If you repeat this exercise with 0.5 transparency, the 7<sup>th</sup> circle will only leave a total transparency of 0.5<sup>7</sup> = 0.0078125. And that really means the opacity is 0.992. It is normal that you don't see the background any more then.